# How do I change other part of the colour in progressbar Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a battery in my app. Here is the screenshot that my battery looks like.

[image]

I would like to change gray color to different colors programmatically.

Here is code to display battery

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/batteryFramLayout"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/settingsBtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/settingsBtn" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/batteryIndicaterBar"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBarHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:max="100"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressBackgroundTintMode="src_atop"
        android:progressTint="@color/green"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/battery">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <org.ros.android.view.RosTextView
        android:id="@+id/batteryPercentageTxtView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```